# Hot reload blazor via dotnet watch not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor

I don't know if anyone encountered any issues like this but since I upgraded to VS 17.0.4, Hot reload does not work anymore (via dotnet watch or VS) for my blazor wasm application.
Dotnet watch correctly detect any changes but does not restart or apply hot reload changes, it just displays this message : **File changed : c:\xxx**.

When I hit ctrl+r, nothing happens. I tried to reinstall Vs 17.0.0 but the error did not got away, any ideas ?

PS: working with .net 6.0.101

Comment: Hosted or standalone WASM? How are you starting the application? With or without debugging?

Comment: I know that with debugging it's currently not possible, so without, it's hosted asp.net core but even standalone it's not working. I am starting the application either by ctrl+f5 or dotnet watch via CLI but neither are working =(

Comment: Having this same problem when using remote ssh development.   I start it with dotnet watch run.   If I run it from inside a local container, it works fine.   When I use remote ssh into another machine and run it, the console shows an update, but you can not see the "Do you want to restart..." question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Changing the ports in launchsettings.json fixed the issue, no idea why but it did

Comment: I don't know why, but it work for me too. 
Blazor Webassembly

Comment: That doesn't make sense though. Thanks. I was going mad.

Comment: Thanks I was going mad with this too. latest VS preview 2022 .Net 8 Preview

Comment: sorry nope that only sorted it out for a few minutes back to its usual tricks

Comment: a life saver +1

Comment: Changing what there?